# Java Application : repaint isn't executed in While Loop?

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I've got this `Thread` that is supposed to Update the game's elements, i.e. repaint, wait for a bit of time then do it again, the problem is that it doesn't repaint. I've tested every other component, they all works, but the paint method is only called once ( Because the components are painted ), even if I call `repaint()` in the loop. Here's my Code of the Loop:

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
public void run()
    {
        mouse.init();
        while(true)
        {                                       
         mouse.Refresh();//Adds Dirty Regions in the RepaintManager   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {    
       @Override 
       public void run() {              
          //What here? 
       }
    });


        }            
    }
};
```

No need to see the thread or anything, it loops.

Here's the Paint Method :

```
   @Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

            EndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//For the FPS Counter
    Time = EndTime - StartTime;
    FPS = (byte) (1000/Time);   
    TotalFPS += FPS;
    TotalFrame++;   
            JPT.AverageFPs.setText( "" + TotalFPS/TotalFrame);
            JPT.CurrentFPS.setText( "" + FPS);
    StartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    g.clearRect(0,0,dim.width,dim.width); 


    for(int x = 0; x < Variables.Width; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < Variables.Height; y++)
        {
            if(Variables.Map[x][y] == 0)
            { 
                g.setColor(new Color(0x613F37));
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            }
            else if(Variables.Map[x][y] == 1)
            { 
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            }
            else if(Variables.Map[x][y] == 2)
            { 
                g.setColor(new Color(0xDEDEDE));
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            }

        }
    }

        g.setColor( new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
        g.fillRect(Variables.CurrentX, Variables.CurrentY, Variables.Zoom, Variables.Zoom);





}
```

Thanks alot in advance.

Also I want to point out that I made this Game as an Applet before and it was working like a charm, but now I need it as Application.

Comment: Why are you repainting an obnoxious amount?

Comment: @Moonbeam: If that's an obnoxious amount, I'd hate to know what you might say about some of my code. Ahem.. shouldn't the FPS calcs be outside of the paint method? Brilliant resource: http://goo.gl/3Wf1f

Comment: It's goes against the Java convention to have variable names and method names starting with capital letters.  For example, it seems that `Variable` is a class rather than an object.

Comment: It could be but I just made it there since it updates the FPS Labels and that's like 'painting' but whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data is not synchronized between threads (there is not enough code to determine if this the case tough).

`repaint` is called on the Swing EDT and `update.UpdateGravity()` is called in your main thread.  I guess your `update` changes `Variable`, but do you ever synchronize this data structure such that the Swing EDT sees the updated value?

**EDIT**:

here is what you should do:

```
variables = update.updateGravity();  // runs in your main thread
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {    
   @Override public void run() {
       yourCustomSwingComponent.update(variables);   // will run on the Swing EDT
   }
}
```

and `yourCustomSwingComponent` contains the `paint()` method you have.  There is a rule in Swing that the state of any Swing component can only be modified (or read) from the Swing EDT.

You should read about Swing and multi-threading.  Actually, you **must** read about multi-threading to use Swing.

Comment: I didn't added more then one thread for now, I just wanted to make it work before making it better

Comment: After some more research in my code, I realize you're right, even if the variables are changed, the same thing is drawn ( A bit of progress since before it weren't drawing more then once )

Comment: If you are using Swing, you are using at least two threads.  Swing runs in the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT).

Comment: Your code is giving my errors, but thanks for showing me the way. And yes, I started to read on MultiThreading after that but not that easy.

Comment: It can successfully change and access variables in the painter class, but not outside

Comment: Your program structure is not quite clear from the code you have given.  But I now think that when I wrote `yourCustomSwingComponent` I simply meant your `Painter`.  Maybe you can only access `variables` from your `Painter` for now, but what I'm telling you is to change your program structure: you update `variables` from the main thread with `updateGravity()` and then you update the __other__ `variables` in the Swing EDT using  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and some new method `painter.update(variables)` which you'll have to add.

Comment: But which other variables are you talking about? All my variables are changed in the Update Class, the only variables changed in painter are the FPS counter which works just fine and the Double Buffering ( Which doesn't work right now ). Do you mean repaint using invokeLater?

Comment: I also use RM.addDirtyRegion because after alot of trials and errors, if I use that plus painter.repaint, it seems to hit 77 FPS, but still doesn't get the updated variables

Comment: When I write `variables`, I mean your variable `Variables` which I guessed is what is modified in `updateGravity`. (As I mentioned in the comments you should never have a variable name starting with a capital.)  What I mean is that you should keep two separate copies of `variables`: one that you update with `updateGravity` in the main thread and one that inside `Painter` that you update by calling `painter.update(variables)` with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.  And no, don't call `repaint` with `invokeLater`; it's already done by default.

Comment: I quite don't understand what you mean or how to do that. See my updated code, it may help you

Answer (score 3):

Try `paintImmediately(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());`

Comment: You have to call it from the EDT. Look up calling paintImmediately() from a different thread.

Comment: @paranoid-android if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread) {...} +1

Answer (score 2):

This is because the [RepaintManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html) collapses multiple requests into a single repaint for members of a component tree.

Comment: This is true, however I believe that `paintImmediately` forces an update if you use it right.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the question directly, but it might be very useful to have a look at some of the existing Java2D animation libraries. For example, [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home) originally developed by [Kirill Grouchnikov](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/). If there is a reason not to use it, at least it could be useful to inspect the source and borrow some ideas.

Also, [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) could be of some interest for implementing time based Swing related actions.

Comment: @MasterMind555 That's why it might be easier to use a ready, well tested lib.